# Anyway to enable solution level SSL using dotnet CLI?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, powershell, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I am using `dotnet` CLI to run projects through a Powershell script. There is an SSL notification that pops up when we load the solution for the first time, which gives Yes/No options. I want to accept that or set the SSL to true using `dotnet` CLI.

This is the error that occurs when SSL is not enabled,

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
```

Answer (score 0):

Before executing HTTPS Request. Add below Line of code. It will resolve the issue

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
```

Comment: Thanks @Tech-leo, Can this be done using dotnet cli ?

Comment: yes you can add this in your Program.cs file

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the SSL needed to be trusted. The Project was able to execute without any iisSettings as well.

This commands helps in trusting the ssl certificates.

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

This [Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/configuring-https-in-asp-net-core-across-different-platforms/) and [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/6066) helped me a lot.